# Android Google maps cluster zoom out

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using clustermanager with google maps, I have a problem that when I zoom out for example all my markers are in swiss, but when I zoom out the cluster that group 10 markers for example showed that it is in germany, but I zoomed in again it return to swiss.

So what I have to do to let the cluster in swiss, even if the user change the zoom level.

Best Regards,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If understood you right you want that the cluster don't align perfectly in a grid.

Try set the algorithm in the cluster manager.

```
NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<MyClusterItem> non = new NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<>();
mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(non);
```